# How to reconstruct geometric object that a Frobenius group acts on

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-mathematics, frobenius-groups

A [Frobenius group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group) has equivalent definitions:

1. a transitive permutation group on a finite set such that no non-trivial element fixes more than one point and some non-trivial element fixes a point.
2. has nontrivial malnormal subgroup, $H$, which acts (as a semidirect product) on a normal subgroup $N$, with each element fixing only the identity.

> **Question:** Given a group $G=N\rtimes H$ that is Frobenius by definition 2 (i.e. knowing the isomorphism classes of $H$ and $N$ and the $\varphi:H\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ defining the semidirect product), how can I reconstruct the set in definition $1$ that $G$ is supposed to act on?

My question was motivated by reading user35603's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8938640) which illustrates how to view $C_p\rtimes C_2$ (with $p$ odd) as a Frobenius group using the first definition.  It is very visual and we can see that it is Frobenius by #1.  Can our reconstruction be similarly geometric and intuitive?

Comment: The link to the answer you mentioned does not seem to work. Could you fix it, as it appears to be essential to understand your question.

Comment: It's the action in which $G$ acts by multiplication on the left on the left cosets of $H$: $g \in G$ maps coset $g'H$ to coset $gg'H$). (Or replace left by right if you prefer right actions.)